# Difference Between Value attribute and explicit DataTrigger.Value in ResourceDictionary?

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid, resourcedictionary

Can anyone tell me why the following doesn't work, but the one after it does? Notice the Value= syntax versus the explicit usage on the latter. I don't understand the difference.

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ItemType}" Value="{x:Type log:FranchiseAiring}">
        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource FranchiseRowStyle}" />
    </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Above throws an exception, below works fine:

```
<Style.Triggers>
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ItemType}">
    <DataTrigger.Value>
        <x:Type Type="{x:Type log:FranchiseAiring}" />
    </DataTrigger.Value>
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource FranchiseRowStyle}" />
</DataTrigger>
```

Exception:
**Must specify both Binding and Value for DataTrigger**.  Error at object 'System.Windows.DataTrigger' in markup file ';component/ResourceDictionaries/LogStyles.xaml' Line 14 Position 15.

Stack Trace:
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException.ThrowException(String message, Exception innerException, Int32 lineNumber, Int32 linePosition, Uri baseUri,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It it probably caused by the bug Anurag linked to, but you should be aware that the two examples you used are not precisely identical from a XAML point of view.

If you convert this to element property syntax

```
Value="{x:Type whatever}"
```

what you get is:

```
<DataTrigger.Value>
  <x:Type TypeName="whatever">
</DataTrigger.Value>
```

What you wrote in your question actually corresponds to

```
Value="{x:Type Type={x:Type whatever}}"
```

Because of the semantics of TypeExtension, both ought to produce the same value in every situation I can think of.  But for other purposes they may be different, and they may tickle different bugs in WPF.

Because of this, it is possible that `Value="{x:Type Type={x:Type log:FranchiseAiring}}"` might work for you.  You may want to try it and find out.

Comment: +1.  This is because `Type` is marked as a `[ConstructorArgument]` property.  But in this case, the behaviour should be identical.

Answer (score 2):

It is a bug that has been fixed. Check this:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/3fd23613-6f1d-4ae6-a279-b99d6fdbc374